# Unable to send email using codeigniter-Error:Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send email from live server using domain email id. I tried with different port id, every time I got same error.My controller code is given below:

```
public function send_mail() {
            $this->load->library('email');
            $name = $this->input->post("name");
            $email = $this->input->post("email");
            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
            $config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.*******.com';
            $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
            $config['smtp_user'] = 'info@*******.com';
            $config['smtp_pass'] = '*********';
            $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
            $config['newline'] = '\r\n';
            $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html
            $config['validation'] = TRUE;

            $this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->from('info@*******.com', 'Hima');
            $this->email->to($email);
            $this->email->subject('email verification');
            $this->email->message('Verification Code');
            $send = $this->email->send();
            if ($send) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','success');
            } else {
                echo $error = $this->email->print_debugger();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have configured like following :

```
public function send_mail() { 
    $this->load->library('encrypt');
    $config = array(
                     'protocol' => 'smtp',
                     'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                     'smtp_port' => '465',
                     'smtp_user' => '*****@gmail.com',
                     'smtp_pass' => '**********',
                     'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
                     'crlf' => "\r\n",
                    );
       $this->load->library('email',$config);
       $send = $this->email->send();
            if ($send) {
                return $send;
            } else {
                $error = show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                return $error;
            }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sir,i want to send mail from our domain mail id,then how can i give smtp_host